# cURL.exe on Windows 7 - Not a valid win32 application?

Tags: ms-access, curl, command-line

I have an AccessDB application that attempts to run cURL.exe to perform a PASV file transfer to a 3rd party using a command shell.

All is working as expected under Windows 10.

One of our partner users is having issues running from Windows 7 (64bit).  He has grabbed the 64bit version cURL.exe but is seeing an error msg:  "...application is not a valid Win32 application".

cURL.exe is a standalone executable, no DLLs, etc.

In a similar manner, their Windows8 users cannot run the the command line from the command shell via my VBA application, but they CAN run manually from command line itself.

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Download/build a version that works?

Comment: How are you calling/running the `curl` executable from Access?

Comment: I am calling via Wscript command shell. Works OK from Win10 from Access and from plain old command line from Win10 & Win8.  Just not Win7.